# Detect two or more same character in one string

Tags: jquery

Simple Question.
How can I detect if my string contains two same character on input keyup. I prefer to do this in jquery

```
test >> true
abcd >> false
```

I've tried

```
  $('#input-id').on('keyup', function(event) {
    if($('#input-id:contains("t")').length >= 2){
       alert('123');
    }
  });
```

but this is not working

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dsx2t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var input = $('inputId').value;
var count = (input.match(/t/g) || []).length;  // 't' is a search string
if(count > 1)
 return true;
else
 return false;
```

Comment: ok this works. i'll accept this. thanks. I know i should post another question but what if I want to replace that second character with a blank?

Comment: `var pos = input.search("t");
var inputSubstr = input.substr(pos+1);
var inputNew = inputSubstr.replace(/t/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ==>

```
var str= $('inputId').value;
var hasrepeat = (/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test(str)        
alert(hasrepeat); // return true OR false if true=repeat false= Not repeat
```